# Regex to remove white spaces

Tags: regex

I need a regex to remove all white spaces in a string of css except those in between selectors
For example:
input

```
#id .class .anotherclass { color: #555 } #anotherid .class { color : #fff; }
```

output

```
#id .class .anotherclass{color:#555}#anotherid .class{color:#fff;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're using php, based on that, try this:

```
<?
$text = "#id .class .anotherclass { color: #555 } #anotherid .class { color : #fff; }";
function removespaces($matches)
{
return $matches[1].str_replace(" ", "", $matches[2]);
}
echo preg_replace_callback( "/(#.*?)(\{.*?\})/i", "removespaces", $text);
?>
```

***DEMO:***

http://ideone.com/T5Qzc6